# Filtering OData query for guid not working in PowerQueryEditor

Tags: excel, odata, powerquery

in Excel's PowerQueryEditor I'm using an ODataFeed to connect to a MicrosoftProject Server. So far I've been able to filter my queries just fine using the eq operator. Earlier however when trying to filter for an ID I've encountered an issue that I've not been able to resolve since. What I tried so far:

```
&$filter=ResourceId eq '36e5e546-770e-e911-80ef-005056b222bb'
```

Error message:

> An error occurred in the ‘’ query. DataSource.Error: OData: A binary
>   operator with incompatible types was detected. Found operand types
>   'Edm.Guid' and 'Edm.String' for operator kind 'Equal'

```
&$filter=ResourceId eq 36e5e546-770e-e911-80ef-005056b222bb
```

> An error occurred in the ‘’ query. DataSource.Error: OData: Syntax
>   error at position 22 in 'ResourceId eq
>   36e5e546-770e-e911-80ef-005056b222bb'.

Any help would be highly apreciated

Comment: It would probably help to show the broader code context of how this request is setup in Power Query. Off hand I would guess you could also try double-double quotes ("") around the ID maybe, since this is probably being passed through as a string?

Comment: After a long and weary trial and error process I was able to solve it myself. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone else ever stumbles across this, I managed to solve this using

```
ResourceId eq (guid'36e5e546-770e-e911-80ef-005056b222bb')
```